Review not needed after review
After reviewing a paper 1 month ago, I received the following email:
"It has since become clear that I will not need you to review the submitted manuscript at this time."
Has anyone encountered this? What should I think about this?

Did you return your review to the editor?

Yes I got an email that confirmed it. I got this message after the submitted review.

Sounds like somebody hit the wrong button in their software...

But the review was deleted on the website today. Does this mean anything?

Perhaps the editors cat walked across the keyboard. Ultimately, they are moving on without your review, not sure what else to do but let the editor know something was wonky in handling it.

There are a lot of possibilities, among them that the editor made a decision with or without reviews. Another is that the author(s) withdrew the paper making reviews moot.
The timing might just be a coincidence and the editor might not have noticed your review submission. Don't read too much in to it. It is unlikely that it reflects badly on you or your review.

Should I still ask why this happened or leave it as it is?

You could leave it without issue, but if curiosity is killing you, ask. You might not get a reply if the editor is overworked at the moment.

This has happened to me twice in recent years. In one case the very short paper was quickly found (not by me) to be a nearly word-for-word match with someone's (not the paper's author) mathoverflow answer. I knew the editor, so I asked what were the "problematic issues" found by another reviewer (this being before I had gotten around to looking carefully at the paper), since in my initial glance at the paper it seemed correct, but possibly not interesting or profound enough for the journal (neither of which seemed to merit the wording the editor used).

From an editor's perspective, this doesn't look good, and this isn't how the process should be run. "The review is no longer needed" notices make sense in case a paper is withdrawn, or a decision can be made before having received the review (which may be late, but also an earlier review may have highlighted issues that actually "kill" the paper regardless of what a later reviewer could say, such as proof for plagiarism).
It is frustrating for the reviewer to have their review ignored, but also from an editor's perspective it doesn't make sense not to use all available information, i.e., already submitted reviews.
Of course, as others write, the reason may be a harmless mistake, but as editor I would absolutely want to know that this happened, to investigate why it happened and whether there is a reason to review the decision. So I encourage you to write to the editor and ask what was going on.
By the way, editorial work in science, even if often not paid for, is a responsible position and requires a professional attitude. I can't agree with the "let it go, chances are it's harmless and the editor has too much to do anyway" sound of some contributions. Of course you don't have an obligation to chase this up, but as I said, as an editor I'd welcome you to do it.

The simplest possibility would be that your submitted review got lost in the system, or the editor overlooked or forgot about it. This happens sometimes and is of course frustrating: Reviewing a revision, after the original review did not reach the authors
The second simplest reason is that someone misclicked, as Jon Custer notes.
In either case, apparently the editor reached a decision without requiring your review. Since you saw the paper, you are likely in the best situation to judge whether this is good news or bad news for the author(s).
As others write, you can certainly ask what happened. That your review was deleted is indeed strange, I have never heard of that (to be honest, I usually don't hunt for my reviews on the system afterwards), so this might well warrant a polite inquiry.

Thank you for your answer. I will ask to resolve the situation.

They found another reviewer who completed the job. This may happen if you took too much time, but also sometimes, if they just got enough reviews. I wouldn't worry too much.

But I met the deadline, and my review was also accessible on their website long after the deadline.

That's strange. I would ping them and tell them that you submitted your review.
